# Using async await when implementing a library with both synchronous and asynchronous API for the same functionality

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dry

I've got a few questions about how to provide both synchronous and asynchronous implementation of the same functionality in a library. I am gonna ask them first and then provide the example code below (which is actually quite a bit, but in fact it's quite simple).

1. Is there an approach to avoid violating the DRY principle? Consider the implementations of `JsonStreamReader.Read`, `JsonStreamWriter.Write`, `JsonStreamWriter.Flush`, `ProtocolMessenger.Send`, `ProtocolMessenger.Receive` and their asynchronous versions.
2. Is there an approach to avoid violating the DRY principle when unit testing both synchronous and asynchronous versions of the same method? I am using NUnit, although I guess all frameworks should be the same in this regard.
3. How should be implemented a method returning `Task` or `Task<Something>` considering the `Take 1` and `Take 2` variants of `ComplexClass.Send` and `ComplexClass.Receive`? Which one is correct and why?
4. Is it correct to always include `.ConfigureAwait(false)` after `await` in a library considering it is not known where the library will be used (Console application, Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET)?

And here follows the code I am referring to in the first questions.

`IWriter` and `JsonStreamWriter`:

```
public interface IWriter
{
    void Write(object obj);
    Task WriteAsync(object obj);
    void Flush();
    Task FlushAsync();
}

public class JsonStreamWriter : IWriter
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;

    public JsonStreamWriter(Stream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream;
    }

    public void Write(object obj)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        _stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    public async Task WriteAsync(object obj)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        await _stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        _stream.Flush();
    }

    public async Task FlushAsync()
    {
        await _stream.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

`IReader` and `JsonStreamReader`:

```
public interface IReader
{
    object Read(Type objectType);
    Task<object> ReadAsync(Type objectType);
}

public class JsonStreamReader : IReader
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;

    public JsonStreamReader(Stream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream;
    }

    public object Read(Type objectType)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = _stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, objectType);
        return obj;
    }

    public async Task<object> ReadAsync(Type objectType)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = await _stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
        string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, objectType);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

`IMessenger` and `ProtocolMessenger`:

```
public interface IMessenger
{
    void Send(object message);
    Task SendAsync(object message);
    object Receive();
    Task<object> ReceiveAsync();
}

public interface IMessageDescriptor
{
    string GetMessageName(Type messageType);
    Type GetMessageType(string messageName);
}

public class Header
{
    public string MessageName { get; set; }
}

public class ProtocolMessenger : IMessenger
{
    private readonly IMessageDescriptor _messageDescriptor;
    private readonly IWriter _writer;
    private readonly IReader _reader;

    public ProtocolMessenger(IMessageDescriptor messageDescriptor, IWriter writer, IReader reader)
    {
        _messageDescriptor = messageDescriptor;
        _writer = writer;
        _reader = reader;
    }

    public void Send(object message)
    {
        Header header = new Header();
        header.MessageName = _messageDescriptor.GetMessageName(message.GetType());

        _writer.Write(header);
        _writer.Write(message);
        _writer.Flush();
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(object message)
    {
        Header header = new Header();
        header.MessageName = _messageDescriptor.GetMessageName(message.GetType());

        await _writer.WriteAsync(header).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _writer.WriteAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _writer.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public object Receive()
    {
        Header header = (Header)_reader.Read(typeof(Header));
        Type messageType = _messageDescriptor.GetMessageType(header.MessageName);
        object message = _reader.Read(messageType);
        return message;
    }

    public async Task<object> ReceiveAsync()
    {
        Header header = (Header)await _reader.ReadAsync(typeof(Header)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Type messageType = _messageDescriptor.GetMessageType(header.MessageName);
        object message = await _reader.ReadAsync(messageType).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return message;
    }
}
```

`ComplexClass`:

```
public interface ISomeOtherInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class ComplexClass : IMessenger, ISomeOtherInterface
{
    private readonly IMessenger _messenger;
    private readonly ISomeOtherInterface _someOtherInterface;

    public ComplexClass(IMessenger messenger, ISomeOtherInterface someOtherInterface)
    {
        _messenger = messenger;
        _someOtherInterface = someOtherInterface;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _someOtherInterface.DoSomething();
    }

    public void Send(object message)
    {
        _messenger.Send(message);
    }

    // Take 1
    public Task SendAsync(object message)
    {
        return _messenger.SendAsync(message);
    }

    // Take 2
    public async Task SendAsync(object message)
    {
        await _messenger.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public object Receive()
    {
        return _messenger.Receive();
    }

    // Take 1
    public Task<object> ReceiveAsync()
    {
        return _messenger.ReceiveAsync();
    }

    // Take 2
    public async Task<object> ReceiveAsync()
    {
        return await _messenger.ReceiveAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 3.?

Comment: I provided 2 implementations for the same async method: one with Take 1 comment above it and the other with Take 2. I mean - which one is correct and why?

Comment: Got it. Added that to my answer.

Comment: Not sure if you're maybe stumbling down the route that [Should I expose async wrappers for synchronous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) tries to steer people away from.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I read both articles before posting my question. Even in the first of my examples you'll see that I am not taking that road. It would be better if you had read them before assuming though. Thanks for pointing that out anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general answer here is that making both **truly `async`** and sync versions of the same functionality requires **2 different (maybe similar, maybe not) implementations**. You can try and find duplicate parts and reuse them using a base class (or a utility class) but the implementations would mostly be different.

In many cases, people choose to only supply one version of the API, be it asynchronous or not. For example the [.Net client library for YouTube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#retrieve_my_uploads) is entirely `async` all the way through. If you can afford that (many can't) that would be my recommendation.

### About your specific questions:

1. Not really, other than finding similar parts and abstracting them away.
2. Not really, synchronous methods need to be tested in a synchronous context while `async` ones in an `async` context.
3. `Take 1` (i.e. returning a task directly) is preferable in 2 ways:

   - It lacks the overhead of creating the whole unneeded `async` state machine which adds a *very slight* performance boost.
   - `ConfigureAwait` in this case affects only the code that comes after it, which in this case is none at all. It doesn't affect the caller's code whether it uses `ConfigureAwait` or not.
4. Definitely yes (finally, positivity). `async` code in libraries should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` by default, and remove it only when there's a specific need to.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, APIs should be either asynchronous or synchronous. E.g., if your implementation includes I/O, it should be asynchronous.

That said, there are scenarios where you do want to have both synchronous and asynchronous APIs. E.g., if the work is naturally asynchronous, but the synchronous APIs need to be kept for backwards compatibility.

If you're in that situation, I recommend using the [boolean argument hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx) to minimize the amount of duplicated code. [Asynchronous wrappers over synchronous methods](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) and [synchronous wrappers over asynchronous methods](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) are both antipatterns.

Comment: I've looked at all the different answers on different questions.  People unhelpfully handwave say "You never need sync, it should always be async."  Others point to an AsyncHelper context, or any variety of things  which your articles cover, and the only reliable answer that hasn't been associated with an "It deadlocks for me" is your boolean suggestion.  I recommend it to anyone who needs to wrap async with sync.

Comment: Yes, the boolean argument hack is my personal favorite. It's not actually a way to wrap async with sync, though. It creates a single (private) method that can be async *or* sync, and then you have async and sync wrappers around that. So it avoids the problems with sync-over-async and async-over-sync because it doesn't actually wrap one with the other.